# What needs to fix to not give error to the Trigger PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

When I script this trigger it gives me these errors.

1. "Statement ignored"
2. C. CREDENTIALS: invalid identifier.
3. Invalid use of loop index variable 'C_Cursor'.

Solutions?

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_VENDITE
  AFTER INSERT ON VENDITE_STG
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  CURSOR s1 IS 
    SELECT L.ID_LIBRO,C.ID_CLIENTE,L.TITOLO,C.CREDENIZALI
      FROM LIBRI L INNER JOIN VENDITE V ON L.ID_LIBRO=V.ID_LIBRO
     INNER JOIN CLIENTI C ON V.ID_CLIENTE=C.ID_CLIENTE;
BEGIN 
  FOR C_cursor IN s1
  LOOP
    IF C_cursor.TITOLO=NEW.TITOLO 
       AND C_cursor.CREDENZIALI=NEW.CREDENZIALI
       AND TO_CHAR(:NEW.DATA_VENDITA,'DD/MM/YYYY')='09/01/2022'
       AND NEW.TIPO_ACQUISTO=1 THEN
      INSERT INTO VENDITE(ID_LIBRO,ID_CLIENTE,DATA_VENDITA,TIPO_ACQUISTO) 
             VALUES(VR_ID_LIBRO ,C_cursor.ID_CLIENTE ,:NEW.DATA_VENDITA,'Contanti');
       EXIT;
    ELSIF I.TITOLO=NEW.TITOLO
          AND I.CREDENZIALI=NEW.CREDENZIALI
          AND TO_CHAR(:NEW.DATA_VENDITA,'DD/MM/YYYY')='09/01/2022'
          AND NEW.TIPO_ACQUISTO=2 THEN
      INSERT INTO VENDITE(ID_LIBRO,ID_CLIENTE,DATA_VENDITA,TIPO_ACQUISTO) 
             VALUES(I.ID_LIBRO ,I.ID_CLIENTE ,:NEW.DATA_VENDITA,'Carta di Credito');
      EXIT;
    ELSIF C_cursor.TITOLO=NEW.TITOLO
          AND C_cursor.CREDENZIALI=NEW.CREDENZIALI
          AND TO_CHAR(:NEW.DATA_VENDITA,'DD/MM/YYYY')='09/01/2022'
          AND NEW.TIPO_ACQUISTO=3 THEN
      INSERT INTO VENDITE(ID_LIBRO,ID_CLIENTE,DATA_VENDITA,TIPO_ACQUISTO) 
             VALUES(C_cursor.ID_LIBRO ,C_cursor.ID_CLIENTE ,:NEW.DATA_VENDITA,'Buono');
      EXIT;
    END IF; 
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing some ":" prefixes for your NEW references

Comment: 1. There's no `C. CREDENTIALS` in this code. 2. Errors  should be followed by the line number, where it appears. Please, add full error message to the question. 3. `I.TITOLO` doesn't exist in the context it was used, because variables `I` was not declared. 4. You will loop over all the results of that `join` **for every row inserted**, while you actually need only rows with `TITOLO=NEW.TITOLO ... etc`. It would be better to add filters to the query. But the `loop` is not required at all, you may use `insert... select` with `case` expression to process 1, 2 and 3 values of `NEW.TIPO_ACQUISTO`

Comment: The code looks a bit weird. Why select many rows only to dismiss all that dont match TITOLO and CREDENZIALI? Why not only select only matching rows in the first place? Then, you only insert rows, if the VENDITE_STG.DATA_VENDITA is a certain date. Why do you check this condition inside the loop? It is completely independent from the loop, so why even enter the loop, when the date does not match? Then, you stop at the first match, so why not select a single row? Maybe you want to tell us what you want to achieve and how the tables are related, so we can tell you how to write the trigger.